# How to make jenkins archive file content and not the soft link?

Tags: jenkins

How to make Jenkins archive the real content of the file which the softlink points to. The real file contains timestamps, and there are many of them in the workspace, but the softlink points to the latest version, and is convenient to enter into the artifact post archive task.